# Cannot read property of undefined angular 2 even when input fields are populated

Tags: angular

I have a service that gets the identity from an api as shown below.

```
getUserClaims() {
 return this.http.get(this.rootUrl+'/api/GetUserClaims');
}
```

And in my `home.component.ts` I invoke it as follows.

```
userClaims: any;
ngOnInit() {
  this.userService.getUserClaims().subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.userClaims = data; 
  });
}
```

And I use the `userClaims` in the input element of the `home.component.html` like so:

```
<div class="col s12 m8 l9" >
  <ul class="collapsible collapsible-accordion" data-collapsible="accordion">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header active ">User Detail</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body">
          <div class="card ">
              <br>
                <div class="card-image" *ngIf="base64textString != null">
                  <img [src]="'data:image/jpg;base64,'+base64textString" style="padding-left: 20px; border-radius: 50%; width: 25%; height: 25%"/>
                </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <table>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td><span style="font-weight:bold;">UserId </span></td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <input [disabled]="disabledInput" value="{{userClaims.UserId}}" type="text" class="validate">
                        </div>
                      </td>  
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td><span style="font-weight:bold;">Username </span></td>
                      <td>
                        <div class="input-field">
                            <input [disabled]="disabledInput" value="{{userClaims.UserName}}" type="text" class="validate">
                        </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr> .........
```

When I log in, I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'UserId' of undefined

And my inputs do not show. But when I refresh, that's the time when my input elements gets populated but the error still persists in the devconsole.

Any pointers in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using [safe navigation operator ( ?. ) and null property paths](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths) `?`

```
{{userClaims?.UserId}} // {{userClaims?.your_property}}
```

As you are trying to access the property before its available ,

---

another way is to use `*ngIf` to check if variable is not `null` and have values

```
<div *ngIf='userClaims'>
   // Put your all code within this block
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the first suggestion. I actually tried the first suggestion before posting this question but I still got the error. The first one did the trick. But it just solved half of it. In my login, the input elements does not show and there is no error but when I refresh it, my input elements show up. Can you help me with that please.

Comment: @stackquestions , can you create a demo on stackblitz , it would be better for me to debug.

Comment: I would love to but I am new to web development and I don't know how to create that demo on stackblitz yet.

Comment: @stackquestions , just go to https://stackblitz.com/ and click on angular then you will get the idea

Comment: I will do that as soon as I get in front of the computer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you're receiving your data "too late".

Angular is trying to render `{{userClaims.UserId}}` before your service actually returns the data.

You can either wrap your inputs in div with `*ngIf="userClaims"` or use safe navigation operator:

`{{userClaims?.UserId}}`

Comment: If I use *ngIf="userClaims", the input field does not load even if I refresh it multiple times. I think you're right in saying that "Angular is trying to render {{userClaims.UserId}} before your service actually returns the data". Do you have an idea to delay the input fields from showing until it gets the data?

Comment: Safe navigation operator is doing just that, delaying rendering untill the object is ready.